# How to recover from cisco 3750 console lockout if the login method is set to login local but no local usernames are configured?

Tags: cisco

I have two 3750G stacked and I am locked out of console access. The startup-config console settings are login and local. However, there is no local database, i.e, no username and password is specified. After attempting the normal password recovery (init_flash, load_helper, dir, rename, etc) and booting, the console screen still shows the "username" prompt. And since there is no username I am stuck. The switches are not currently in production so I can do anything to them to recover.

Answer (score 1):

restart it and use the serial console to interrupt boot.

Once you're at the switch prompt, do the following:

`flash_init` - initializes the flash (doesn't format it)

`load_helper` - makes the following command accessible

`rename flash:config.text flash:config.text.prev`

`boot`

Once it's booted, I'd suggest copying off the old config, modifying it with a user and then loading it back onto the switch.

Comment: Did that, still boots back to "username" prompt.

Comment: run `dir flash:` after `load_helper` - what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Is this 3750 stacked sometimes you have to disconnect the stack if it is to go to password recovery.

Unless of course somebody configured no  service password config.